# How to delete last part of string in C

Tags: c, string, split, char, strtok

I need a certain part of the string for example I have

`folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4`

and I don't want `folder4` in my new string so it should be like
`folder1/folder2/folder3`

any help would be appreciated I searched for strtok and strchar but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this

Comment: why you don't split by '/'

Comment: Locate the last `/` in the string and insert a zero there, no need for strtok. You can use `strrchr` to search for the last `/` character.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks you have been really helpful I remember you from the other post :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find the last occurance of `/` using `strrchr()` and then replace it with `\0`.

```
int main()
{
    char string[] = "folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4";
    char character = '/'; 
    char* ptr = strrchr(string, character);
    *ptr = '\0';
    cout<<string;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C++ question, it's C. And [you shouldn't include bits/stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right but it doesn't effect the main context of the answer. But anyways i'll remove it. Thanks.